# Send/Save file to URL and process with PHPExcel?

Tags: ms-access, ftp, phpexcel

I use `PHPExcel` to upload Excel data into `MySQL`.

I also have data in `MS Access` that I want to upload to `MySQL`.

Is there somehow that `MS Access` can export a `.xls` file and save it on webserver and process with `PHPExcel`?

I cannot use database connections: `Access -> SQL`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While Access can export table or query data to Excel using the [TransferSpreadsheet](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff844793.aspx), consider directly connecting a [PHP script to MS Access](http://php.net/manual/en/function.odbc-connect.php) importing data into an array and then appending data to MySQL.

Fundamentally, Excel is not a true relational database but a flatfile end-use document like a Word or PDF or XML file. Many use Excel as a database due to its popularity and user-friendliness. But ultimately, it is not an efficient, scalable medium between databases.

Furthermore, Access should not be regarded as a synonymous data store like Excel. It is truly a different product equipped with a front end GUI designer, query processor, report generator, all running on the Jet/ACE SQL engine. Therefore, PHP, Python, R, Java, C#, VB, and other programming languages can connect and query Access databases just as they can with SQL Server, Oracle, DB2, MySQL, PostgreSQL, SQLlite, and others.